# Xcode unrecognized selector sent to instance on device but not simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instance

So I keep getting this error on my ipad Air 2 but on my simulator on ipad 1 ,2, air and air 2 it works without error. I am getting error

`-[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178246f90 on the following code.`

any idea what is going on ?

[image]

Comment: Please copy the full stack trace so we can have an idea on what is wrong. And also, please upload the image here, not to a 3rd party website.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you have a zombie object that is getting deallocated and then later messaged, and there just happens to be an instance of `UICachedDeviceWhiteColor` in that spot in memory on the device but not in the simulator. To debug this, try using the Zombies instrument in the Instruments app. You can find out more information on how to do this here: http://www.markj.net/blog/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie

Comment: Zev is correct, set a breakpoint and inspect the button before calling setFrame on it. You think you are calling setFrame on your button but in reality you are calling it on a deallocated object. Make sure that you are getting the correct object back from objectAtIndex: